# Zsh plugins don't work

Tags: macos, git, zsh, zshrc

I've installed zsh on Mac OS X and zsh doesn't work the proper way.

Themes work fine, but the output of git is not colorized.

What could be wrong?

Here is the piece of my .zshrc:

```
plugins=(git)

export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

`which git` gives me this:

/usr/bin/git

Comment: You mean that you has installed oh-my-zsh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colorizing git output is configured through the `~/.gitconfig`. Have you tried:

```
git config --global color.ui auto
```

More info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/how-to-colorize-output-of-git)

Comment: Thank you very much helped!
As I understand zsh doesn't colorize output and only adds useful commands and aliases, right?

Comment: @EllochkaCannibal zsh colorizes your standard shell commands like `ls`. The colors are configurable through themes. Git is a different program so zsh most probably won't be able to touch that. I've never experienced having an automatically colorized git output when using ZSH (or oh-my-zsh for that matter).

Comment: @Shiki `ls` output is colorized by the `ls` itself. For others one may define an alias that uses something like `grc` to colorize output, but zsh never does anything like coloring output on its own. Zsh may color completion variants and typed command-line though if configured properly.